# laravel policy not working for CamelCase model

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-permission

I am trying to create policy for the custom method which is not working. Each time it returns 403 for the custom method with camelcase naming in laravel 7

Eg.

```
class UserPostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(UserPost::class);
    }

    public function resourceMethodsWithoutModels() 
    {
        return [
            'getListing'
        ];
    }

    public function getListing(UserPostDataTable $dataTable) 
    {
        dd(\Auth::user()->can('viewAny', UserPost::class));

//        $this->authorize('viewAny', UserPost::class);
        return $dataTable->ajax();
    }

//Policy:
use App\User;
use App\UserPost;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;

class UserPostPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return Response::allow()
    }
```

I have already added `$this->registerPolicies();` in boot method of service provider. 
It works with all crud operation of resource but not with custom method.

When I use `UserPost::class` it returns 403.

If I use `User::class` it works perfectly. 
It seems like some naming issue or I am missing out something.

I tried middleware too but not working for camelcase naming.

Don't know how can I add `viewAny` policy for `getListing` method.

Route list:

```
        | GET|HEAD  | UserPost                              | UserPost.index          | App\Http\Controllers\UserPostController@index                       | web,auth:web,can:viewAny,user_post |
|        | POST      | UserPost                              | UserPost.store          | App\Http\Controllers\UserPostController@store                       | web,auth:web,can:create,user_post  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | UserPost/create                       | UserPost.create         | App\Http\Controllers\UserPostController@create                      | web,auth:web,can:create,user_post  |
|        | POST      | UserPost/getListing                   | UserPost.getListing     | App\Http\Controllers\UserPostController@getListing                  | web,auth:web                          |
|        | DELETE    | UserPost/{UserPost}                | UserPost.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\UserPostController@destroy                     | web,auth:web,can:delete,user_post  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | UserPost/{UserPost}                | UserPost.update         | App\Http\Controllers\UserPostController@update                      | web,auth:web,can:update,user_post  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | UserPost/{UserPost}                | UserPost.show           | App\Http\Controllers\UserPostController@show                        | web,auth:web,can:view,user_post    |
|        | GET|HEAD  | UserPost/{UserPost}/edit           | UserPost.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\UserPostController@edit                        | web,auth:web,can:update,user_post
```

Comment: please share the route your controller use

Comment: Found solution: Problem was, I had to explicitly define $policies in AppServiceProvider for custom permission

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->authorizeResource(UserPost::class);
```

this method take a second parameter, this parameter must
match the parameter you use in route

so ... to solve this problem you should use

```
php artisan route:list
```

then find out what is the route parameter name 
( should be userPost ... or user_post) ...
suppose it is user_post ....
then change authorizeResource resource statement to:

```
$this->authorizeResource(UserPost::class,'user_post');
```

and another note:
 in

```
 public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return Response::allow()
    }
```

do not miss setting the parameter name correctly:

```
 public function viewAny(UserPost $user_post) // make sure you use correct parameter name
    {
        return Response::allow()
    }
```

it should work ....

Comment: I tried adding $this->authorizeResource(UserPost::class,'user_post'); but not working. second parameter is the same. I think first argument is User $user only public function viewAny(User $user) .

Comment: Found solution: Problem was, I had to explicitly define $policies in AppServiceProvider for custom permission